Initialize datepicker in other typescript file
I using dattables node module in my project.
It has datetimepickerHelper
Here is content of this file from node modules
    interface JQuery {
    datetimepicker(options: any): JQuery;
    datepickerInit(userOptions: any): JQuery;
    timepickerInit(userOptions: any): JQuery;
    datetimepickerInit(userOptions?: any): JQuery;
    datepicker(userOptions: any): JQuery;
}

(function ($) {

    jQuery.fn.datepickerInit = function (userOptions) {
        var $element = $(this);
        var options = {
            locale: abp.helperConfiguration.getCurrentLanguageLocale(),
            format: 'L'
        };
        options = $.extend(options, userOptions);

        var result = $element.datetimepicker(options);
        return result;
    };

    jQuery.fn.timepickerInit = function (userOptions) {
        var $element = $(this);
        if ($element.val()) {
            $element.val(moment($element.val(), ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss', "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A", 'hh:mm A']).format("LT"));
        }
        var options = $.extend(
            {
                format: 'LT',
                useCurrent: false,
                stepping: 5, //Number of minutes the up/down arrow's will move the minutes value in the time picker
                allowInputToggle: true //show picker on input click
            },
            userOptions);
        return $element.datetimepicker(options);
    };

    jQuery.fn.datetimepickerInit = function (userOptions?: any) {
        var $element = $(this);
        if ($element.val()) {
            $element.val(moment($element.val(), ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss', "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A", 'hh:mm A']).format("L LT"));
        }
        var options = $.extend(
            {
                format: 'L LT',
                useCurrent: false,
                stepping: 1, //Number of minutes the up/down arrow's will move the minutes value in the time picker
                allowInputToggle: true //show picker on input click
            },
            userOptions);
        return $element.datetimepicker(options);
    };

    jQuery.fn.datepicker = function (options) {
        var $element = $(this);
        options = options || { format: 'L' };
        return $element.datetimepicker(options);
    };

})(jQuery);

Also, I have my own .ts file, called dataList.ts, where I try to use datepicker, I mean initialize input with it.
Here is content of dataList file
(function () {
    interface IRowData {
        [field: string]: any;
    }

    interface IDataListOptions {
        listMethod: (params?: any) => Promise<IRowData[]>,
        editMethod: (rowData: IRowData) => Promise<IRowData>,
        deleteMethod: (rowData: IRowData) => Promise<void>,
        columns: IColumnOptions[]
    }

    interface IColumnOptions {
        title: string,
        data: string,
        width?: string,
        editor: ICellEditorConstructor,
        editorOptions: ICellEditorOptions,
        isEditable?: boolean | ((rowData: IRowData, isRowEditable: boolean) => boolean | Promise<boolean>),
        readData?: (rowData: IRowData) => any | Promise<any>,
        writeData?: (value: any, rowData: IRowData) => void | Promise<void>,
        saveOnChange?: boolean;
    }

    interface IDataListApi {
        addRow: (rowData?: IRowData) => void,
        deleteRow: (row: DataListRow) => Promise<void>,
        readValuesFromModel: () => void,
    }


    (jQuery.fn as any).dataListInit = function (dataListOptions: IDataListOptions): IDataListApi {
        var $element = $(this);
        var rows: DataListRow[] = [];
        var api = {
            addRow,
            deleteRow,
            readValuesFromModel
        }

        async function reloadData(params?: any) {
            try {
                //empty();
                dataListHelpers.setBusy($element);
                var rowsData = await dataListOptions.listMethod(params);
                rows = rowsData.map(rowData => new DataListRow(rowData, api, dataListOptions));
                redraw();
            }
            finally {
                dataListHelpers.clearBusy($element);
            }
        }

        function empty() {
            rows.forEach(r => r.destroy());
            $element.empty();
        }

        function redraw() {
            empty();
            if (!rows.length) {
                $element.append(dataListHelpers.getNoRowsPanel());
            } else {
                rows.forEach(row => {
                    $element.append(row.draw());
                });
            }
        }

        function readValuesFromModel() {
            rows.forEach(row => row.readValuesFromModel());
        }

        async function deleteRow(row: DataListRow) {
            if (row.rowData['id']) {
                if (!await (window as any).abp.message.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    dataListHelpers.setBusy(row.panel);
                    await dataListOptions.deleteMethod(row.rowData);
                }
                finally {
                    dataListHelpers.clearBusy(row.panel);
                }
            }
            rows.splice(rows.indexOf(row), 1);
            row.panel.remove();
            if (!rows.length) {
                $element.append(dataListHelpers.getNoRowsPanel());
            }
        }

        function addRow(rowData: IRowData = {}) {
            let row = new DataListRow(rowData, api, dataListOptions);
            if (!rows.length) {
                empty(); //remove the 'no data to display' element
            }
            $element.append(row.draw());
            row.setEditable(true);
            rows.push(row);
        }

        reloadData();


        return api;
    };

    class DataListRow {
        rowData: IRowData;
        dataListApi: IDataListApi;
        dataListOptions: IDataListOptions;
        cells: DataListCell[] = [];
        panel: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        isRowEditable = false;
        #rowContainer: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        #editButton: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        #deleteButton: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        #saveButton: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        #cancelButton: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        constructor(rowData: IRowData, dataListApi: IDataListApi, dataListOptions: IDataListOptions) {
            this.rowData = rowData;
            this.dataListApi = dataListApi;
            this.dataListOptions = dataListOptions;
        }

        draw() {
            this.panel = $('<div class="card card-collapsable card-collapse bg-light mb-4">').append(
                $('<div class="card-header bg-light">').append(
                    $('<div class="d-flex- justify-content-between-">').append(
                        this.#rowContainer = $('<div class="d-flex align-items-end flex-wrap">')
                    )
                )
            );

            this.cells = this.dataListOptions.columns.map(columnOptions => {
                return new DataListCell(this, columnOptions);
            });
            this.cells.forEach(cell => {
                this.#rowContainer.append(cell.draw());
            });

            this.#rowContainer.append(
                $('<div class="datalist-button-container-placeholder">')
            ).append(
                $('<div class="datalist-button-container">').append(
                    this.#editButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">').attr("title", "Edit").append($('<i class="fa fa-edit">'))
                ).append(
                    this.#deleteButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">').attr("title", "Delete").append($('<i class="fa fa-trash">'))
                ).append(
                    this.#cancelButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary close-button">').attr("title", "Cancel").append($('<i class="fa fa-undo">'))
                ).append(
                    this.#saveButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">').attr("title", "Save").append($('<i class="fa fa-save"></i>'))
                )
            );

            this.#editButton.click(() => {
                this.setEditable(true);
            })

            this.#cancelButton.click(async () => {
                this.readValuesFromModel();
                this.setEditable(false);
                if (!this.rowData['id']) {
                    await this.dataListApi.deleteRow(this);
                }
            });

            this.#saveButton.click(async () => {
                let rowDataCopy = $.extend({}, this.rowData);
                try {
                    await this.writeValuesToModel();
                    dataListHelpers.setBusy(this.panel);
                    var result = await this.dataListOptions.editMethod(this.rowData);
                    this.rowData['id'] = result['id'];
                    this.setEditable(false);
                    this.readValuesFromModel();
                }
                catch {
                    $.extend(this.rowData, rowDataCopy); //reverting the model to the original values so that 'cancel' button works correctly
                }
                finally {
                    dataListHelpers.clearBusy(this.panel);
                }
            });

            this.#deleteButton.click(async () => {
                await this.dataListApi.deleteRow(this);
            });

            this.setEditable(this.isRowEditable);

            return this.panel;
        }

        setEditable(isEditable: boolean) {
            this.isRowEditable = isEditable;
            this.cells.forEach(cell => cell.setRowEditable(isEditable));
            this.#editButton.toggle(!isEditable);
            this.#deleteButton.toggle(!isEditable);
            this.#saveButton.toggle(isEditable);
            this.#cancelButton.toggle(isEditable);
        }

        readValuesFromModel() {
            this.cells.forEach(cell => cell.readValueFromModel());
        }

        async writeValuesToModel() {
            for (const cell of this.cells) {
                if (cell.columnOptions.saveOnChange) {
                    continue;
                }
                await cell.writeValueToModel();
            }
            //this.cells
            //    .filter(x => !x.columnOptions.saveOnChange)
            //    .forEach(cell => cell.writeValueToModel());
        }

        destroy() {

        }
    }

    class DataListCell {
        row: DataListRow;
        columnOptions: IColumnOptions;
        editor: DataListAbstractCellEditor;
        isRowEditable: boolean = false;
        constructor(row: DataListRow, columnOptions: IColumnOptions) {
            this.row = row;
            this.columnOptions = columnOptions;
            this.editor = new this.columnOptions.editor(this, this.columnOptions);
        }

        draw() {
            return this.editor.draw();
        }

        readValueFromModel() {
            this.editor.readValueFromModel();
        }

        async writeValueToModel() {
            await this.editor.writeValueToModel();
        }

        setRowEditable(isRowEditable: boolean) {
            this.isRowEditable = isRowEditable;
            this.editor.setRowEditable(isRowEditable);
        }
    }

    interface ICellEditorOptions {
    }
    interface ICellEditorConstructor {
        new (cell: DataListCell, columnOptions: IColumnOptions): DataListAbstractCellEditor;
    }
    abstract class DataListAbstractCellEditor {
        cell: DataListCell;
        row: DataListRow;
        columnOptions: IColumnOptions;
        domElement: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        isRowEditable = false;
        isCellEditable = false;
        constructor(cell: DataListCell, columnOptions: IColumnOptions) {
            this.cell = cell;
            this.row = cell.row;
            this.columnOptions = columnOptions;
        }

        async setRowEditable(isRowEditable: boolean) {
            this.isRowEditable = isRowEditable;
            if (this.columnOptions.isEditable === undefined) {
                this.isCellEditable = isRowEditable;
            } else if (typeof this.columnOptions.isEditable === 'boolean') {
                this.isCellEditable = this.columnOptions.isEditable;
            } else if (typeof this.columnOptions.isEditable === 'function') {
                this.isCellEditable = await Promise.resolve(this.columnOptions.isEditable(this.cell.row.rowData, this.isRowEditable));
            }
            this.refreshEditableState();
        }

        abstract draw(): JQuery<HTMLElement>;

        protected abstract refreshEditableState(): void;

        abstract readValueFromModel(): Promise<any>;
        protected async readValueFromModelInternal(): Promise<any> {
            if (this.columnOptions.readData) {
                return await Promise.resolve(this.columnOptions.readData(this.row.rowData));
            }
            if (this.columnOptions.data) {
                return this.row.rowData[this.columnOptions.data];
            }
            return null;
        }

        abstract writeValueToModel(): Promise<void>;
        protected async writeValueToModelInternal(value: any) {
            value = this.validate(value);
            if (this.columnOptions.writeData) {
                await Promise.resolve(this.columnOptions.writeData(value, this.row.rowData));
            } else if (this.columnOptions.data) {
                this.row.rowData[this.columnOptions.data] = value;
            }
        }

        abstract validate(value: any): any;
        throwValidationError(message: string, input: JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
            input.focus();
            (window as any).abp.notify.error(message);
            throw new Error(message);
        }
    }

    interface TextCellEditorOptions extends ICellEditorOptions {
        maxLength?: number;
        required?: boolean;
    }

    interface DatePickerCellEditorOptions extends ICellEditorOptions {
        required?: boolean;
    }
    class DatePickerCellEditor extends DataListAbstractCellEditor {
        input: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
        editorOptions: TextCellEditorOptions;
        draw(): JQuery<HTMLElement> {
            this.editorOptions = this.columnOptions.editorOptions as DatePickerCellEditorOptions || {};
            this.domElement = $('<div class="form-group mr-4">').append(
                $('<label>').text(this.columnOptions.title)
            ).append(
                this.input = $('<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">').datepicker()
            );

            return this.domElement;
        }

        refreshEditableState() {
            this.input.prop('disabled', !this.isCellEditable);
        }

        async readValueFromModel() {
            var value = await this.readValueFromModelInternal() || '';
            this.input.val(value);
        }

        async writeValueToModel() {
            await this.writeValueToModelInternal(this.input.val());
        }

        validate(value: any): any {
            if (this.editorOptions.required && !value) {
                let message = this.columnOptions.title + ' is required';
                this.throwValidationError(message, this.input);
            }
            return value;
        }
    }


    (window as any).dataList = {
        editors: {
            datepicker: DatePickerCellEditor as ICellEditorConstructor,
        }
    };

    var dataListHelpers = {
        getNoRowsPanel: function () {
            return $('<div class="card card-collapsable card-collapse bg-light mb-4">').append(
                $('<div class="card-header bg-light">').append(
                    $('<div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">').text(
                        (window as any).app.localize("NoDataInTheListClick{0}ToAdd", (window as any).app.localize("AddNew"))
                    )
                )
            );
        },
        getUniqueElementId: function (): string {
            return (window as any).abp.helper.getUniqueElementId();
        },
        setBusy: function (element?: JQuery<HTMLElement>): void {
            (window as any).abp.ui.setBusy(element);
        },
        clearBusy: function (element?: JQuery<HTMLElement>): void {
            (window as any).abp.ui.clearBusy(element);
        }
    };
})();

If I try to initialize like this this.input = $('<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">').datepicker() I have error - TS2339: Property datepicker does not exist on type JQuery
How I can initialize datepicker here?
